# how to indicate the scroll position in listview with moveup and movedown icon

Tags: android, listview

I want to display move up button, when the list view's last item is visible and display move down button, when the list view's first item is visible

I have tried like:

```
lv.setOnScrollListener( new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int lastVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if(lastVisibleItem == totalItemCount)
            {
                imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.move_up);
            }else
                imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.move_down);

        }
    });
```

But It's not working..
Plz help me to solve this.